# codeigniter and form submit

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am trying to get used to Codeigniter. I am sorry if that is a trivial or dumb question but I have been struggling to have the "News Section" of Codeigniter's tutorial work.

There is this form (from [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/create_news_items.html#create-a-form))

```
<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('news/create'); ?>

    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="input" name="title" /><br />

    <label for="text">Text</label>
    <textarea name="text"></textarea><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create news item" />

</form>
```

which, according to [this](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html#display-the-news) controller:

```
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('news_model');
                $this->load->helper('url_helper');
        }

        public function index()
        {
                $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
                $data['title'] = 'My News archive';

                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

        public function view($slug = NULL)
        {
                $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
                if (empty($data['news_item']))
                {
                        show_404();
                }

                $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];


                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('news/', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

        public function create()
        {
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('news/create');
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');

            }
            else
            {
                $this->news_model->set_news();
                $this->load->view('news/success');
            }
        }
}
```

should, I think, if the validation returns ok, go ahead and insert the data into the db. Now, my problem is that the pages run under:

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/news/
```

The submit button, however, returns me to:

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/news/localhost/codeigniter/index.php/news/create
```

The routes.php file contains the following code:

```
$route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'news';
```

I don't know why this is happening. Thank you for any help.

Comment: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set your base_url config in application/config/config.php ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. In my config.php there is this line: $config['base_url'] = 'localhost/codeigniter'; which should set the base_url.

Comment: Could it be this? WOW!! Thanks! I am trying your suggestion right now!

Comment: didn't seem to work. Could you perhaps point me somewhere I could have a look at? Why do you think this error comes about? THANK YOU!

Comment: Having ` $config['base_url']` properly set is a must. `form_open()` along with several other CI functions rely on this value. When it isn't set you end up with whacky urls like you have on your form submit. Try including the protocol like this  `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/;`

Comment: What @DFriend said... you need to include the protocol on the `base_url`, `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/;`

Comment: Thank you all! You saved my day!