# link url in code and in address bar is different than expected

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new on codeigniter and i encounter this problem,
the base_url in config/config.php is 
   `$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/codeigniter/index.php/stud/';`.

and i am using that in view/Stud_view.php

`echo "<td><a href = '".base_url()."/edit/".$r->roll_no."'>Edit</a></td>";`

but in address bar it is appearing as `http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/index.php/stud/edit/21`

here index.php is appearing two times.
If I remove index.php from address bar then it is working fine.
how is this happening?

Comment: Try `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourprojectname/';`  use http in config base url and make sure file and class names only have first letter upper case.

Comment: Which version of Codeigniter are you using?

Comment: What is the URL you want in the link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [codeigniter and form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274969/codeigniter-and-form-submit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `base_url` should be *absolute*, containing the protocol, and it would not include `index.php`:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/
```

Your URL could be constructed as:

```
<?php 
    $url = site_url("stud/edit/" . $r->roll_no);
    echo "<td><a href='" . $url . "'>Edit</a></td>";
?>
```

Your final URL will look like...

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/stud/edit/{roll_no}
```

The `site_url()` function will include "index.php" as defined by your `index_page` configuration setting.  *(The `base_url()` function will **not** include "index.php")*.

See:  [codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#site_url](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#site_url)

Comment: hey thanks,i was also having different problem somewhere else and it worked fine on both places

Answer (score -1):

remove url from base_url config.
change :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/codeigniter/index.php/stud/';
```

to:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

and change your url to :

```
echo "<td><a href = '".site_url()."/edit/".$r->roll_no."'>Edit</a></td>";
```

Comment: after using your method; address changes to `http://127.0.0.1/codeigniter/index.php/edit/23` which is again not working

Comment: If the OP is using a version of codeigniter >= 3.0.0 then this is spectacularly bad advice. Per the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html?highlight=base_url#step-19-make-sure-your-base-url-config-value-is-not-empty) " Make sure your ‘base_url’ config value is not empty". Or, in `config.php` comments on Base Site URL: "WARNING: You MUST set this value!"